# Terminating Loop on Input

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find a way to terminate a loop when the user hits 'x'+Enter. I want the loop to just keep running in the background until the user cancels it.

Something along these lines:

```
while gets.chomp != 'x'

    puts 'looping...'

    sleep 1

end
```

I'm a beginner with programming and have searched far and wide for how to do this so any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: See my gist here: https://gist.github.com/1759451.

Comment: Thanks for the useful loop code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use threads for this:

```
Thread.new do
  while line = STDIN.gets
    break if line.chomp == 'x'
  end
  exit
end

# whatever you want to do in the background
# (or rather in the foreground, actually)
loop do
  puts "foo"
  sleep 1
end
```

The problem is that `STDIN.gets` blocks, so you can't do something else at the same time without parallelizing the program by using a background thread that only checks for input.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! I think I've got it now!

Comment: @niklasb Hi! I was looking for solution to this problem and I could so far find only very similar suggestions, but none of those including yours works for me. Has anything changes in ruby? Thanks. #rubyNewbie