# Ruby: edit thread program to enter function upon termination

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Basically in my search for code which will loop, and terminate upon user input, i managed to find code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219280/terminating-loop-on-input), and after some alteration, produced this:

```
#desired destination method, however loop persists!!

def desired_method 
    print "method entered"
end



Thread.new do
    while line = STDIN.gets
        break if line.chomp == "" # code detects user input
    end
    desired_method
end



# program will loop here until user presses enter

loop do 
    puts "foo"
    sleep 1
end
```

This code is brilliant, and will enter the method 'desired_method' when i hit enter, however the loop persists!! printing 'foo' perpetually after "method entered"!!. I have done some research prior to posting this question on how to kill threads, which i believe may hold the answer. My attempts included naming the thread and using the 'thread.exit' function to kill it, however these techniques have remained unsuccessful.

Can anyone illustrate how i might enter the 'desired_method' method without the persisting "foo" print?

Thanks in advance, and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution here is to use [semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), signalling between threads with a variable access to both places:

```
# This will be out stop flag, for signalling between threads.
@time_to_stop = false

def desired_method 
    print "method entered"
    # Here we want the loop in the other thread to stop.
    @time_to_stop = true
end

Thread.new do
    while line = STDIN.gets
        break if line.chomp == "" # code detects user input
    end
    desired_method
end

# program will loop here until user presses enter
loop do 
    puts "foo"
    sleep 1
    # only continue if the stop flag is not set.
    break if @time_to_stop
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't really a semaphore, just a variable that is used by two threads. There are no race conditions since one thread just reads the variable while the other just writes to it, but still, this isn't a semaphore. Using this technique unguarded just gives you enough rope to hang yourself in other situations. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Mutex.html.

Comment: Is is a very good point. I think I was being a bit hacky to illustrate the point. Care to offer an edit?

Comment: Well, in addition to the variable I'd add a semaphore in the way of `semaphore = Mutex.new` that is used to guard access to the `@time_to_stop` variable, like `semaphore.synchronize { @time_to_stop = true }`. Additionally, I'd add a short explanation on why a single, unguarded variable doesn't help (operations on it aren't atomic). Yes, it looks like overkill on this scenario, but the OP asked a very basic question suggesting he is just learning how to write multi-threaded programs; this is why I'm so anal about this. For extra fanciness, the Mutex alone can be used instead of the variable. :)